# How do I design 5-to-32 decoder using 2-to-4 decoder?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, decoder

As there are 32 outputs in 5-to-32 decoder so I will have to use 32/4 = 8, 2-to-4 decoder. But then I have total 16 inputs. As I want to create 5-to-32 decoder so I need only 5 inputs, what do I do with others?

Answer (score 1):

All of the 8 2-to-4 decoders share their 2 inputs and
you need another 3-to-8 decoder to select only one of those 8 2-to-4 decoders. 
So you have a total of 2 + 3 = 5 inputs.